# How to get the new open page source?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, web-crawler

I'm writing a `Python` crawler using the `Selenium` library and the `PhantomJs` browser. I triggered a click event in a page to open a new page, and then I used the `browser.page_source` method, but I get the original page source instead of the new open page source. I wonder how to get the new open page source?

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://sf.taobao.com/list/50025969__2__%D5%E3%BD%AD.htm?auction_start_seg=-1&page=150'

browser =  webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\\ProgramData\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')   
browser.get(url)    
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='pai-item pai-status-done']").click()    
html = browser.page_source    
print(html)    
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the new window first

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='pai-item pai-status-done']").click()
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])
html = browser.page_source
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add [a wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html?highlight=wait) before getting page source.

I've used an [implicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html?highlight=wait#implicit-waits) at the code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://sf.taobao.com/list/50025969__2__%D5%E3%BD%AD.htm?auction_start_seg=-1&page=150'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\\ProgramData\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')

browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='pai-item pai-status-done']").click()

browser.implicitly_wait(5)

html = browser.page_source

browser.quit()
```

Better to use an [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html?highlight=wait#explicit-waits), but it required a condition like `EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid'))`